# Compile OpenCV with ffMpeg support

Tags: opencv, installation, compilation, ffmpeg

I'm having problems compiling OpenCV with ffMpeg support under Debian.

I downloaded new ffMpeg and installed it, downloaded opencv-1.1pre1.tar.gz and unpacked it.

then

```
./configure --enable-apps --enable-shared --with-ffmpeg --with-gnu-ld --without-quicktime CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
```

ffMpeg checked yes and finally when I make it says

```
../../../otherlibs/highgui/.libs/libhighgui.so: undefined reference to `img_convert'
```

Now I've been around the forums and tried various stuff but nothing worked. 
Can anybody help me get this thing installed?

Comment: OK, I tried the "Leeds Guide to OpenCV" - "Installing OpenCV with ffmpeg" and after some problems i Got it installed finally.

But even after that cvCreateVideoWriter returns "Bad argument (codec not found)  in function cvCreateVideoWriter, cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp(570)" error.

Unbelievable, does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There were some changes in FFmpeg API after OpenCV 1.1pre1 was released, so OpenCV might not work properly with new FFMPEG. I'd suggest trying older versions. I was using FFMPEG trunk snapshot of 07/2008 without problems.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV and FFmpeg evolved very much in last months and nowadays its possible to make [OpenCV 2.1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) work with FFmpeg without much suffering.